# Get timeout error when running inter functional tests

Tags: dojo, intern

I am using intern testing tool with an application developed in dojo 1.8 (using custom template widgets). The page loads successfully in the webdriver but intern is not able to identify the HTML elements and throws timeout error. waitForElementByCssSelector, waitForVisibleById or elementById give timeout error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before anyone can help you.

Comment: Please see below the functional test case code:

Comment: define([
 'intern!object',
 'intern/chai!assert',
 'require'
], function (registerSuite, assert, require) {
 registerSuite({
  name: 'index',

  'greeting form': function () {
   return this.remote
    .get(require.toUrl('scepintern/index.html'))
    .waitForElementByCssSelector('body.loaded', 5000000);
  }
 });
});


It loads the URL successfully but is unable to identify "loaded" css class and throws timeout error.

Comment: That is not enough information to troubleshoot your problem. Does this page you are loading even have such a CSS class? It’s impossible to know, because you haven’t shown it to anyone else but yourself.